# Passing EditText integer to TextView via Intent app crashes after clicking (button) three

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext, textview

I am trying just to pass the int user input to the next class and print it, see that it works before continuing on using it or something else.

Home.java

start and exit button

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToSecondActivity();
            }
        });
        Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    private void goToSecondActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SelectNumberOfPlayers.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

SelectNumberOfPlayers.java
```

Taking only the numbers from the input and passing it to StartGame.class

```
public class SelectNumberOfPlayers extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText numberOfPlayers;
    Button three;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.enter_number_of_players);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){

                String txt = numberOfPlayers.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartGame.class);
                i.putExtra("players", txt);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}

StartGame.java
```

Receiving Int and printing to TextView

```
public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_game);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        TextView numOfPlayersVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        numOfPlayersVal.setText(i.getStringExtra("Player number"));
    }
}
```

Where is the error happening? I've set the input keyboard to take only numbers

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: Why don't you use that extra required text space to post the stack trace, instead of filling it with garbage text?

Comment: You are not initialize the EditText in SelectNumberOfPlayers class that why its crash intialize it

Comment: Do not use blockquote formatting for things that are not quotations. If you want headings, use the heading markdown or simple boldface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. you forgot to  initialize  youe editext  first initialize it in your SelectNumberOfPlayers Activity**

```
numberOfPlayers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfPlayers);
```

**2. 
  the key must be same to pass and receive data with intent**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_game);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    TextView numOfPlayersVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    numOfPlayersVal.setText(i.getStringExtra("players"));
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause a crash.

Comment: Danyavad Mr Nilesh :)

Comment: Not initializing the EditText caused the crash!

Comment: will do @Nilesh Rathod !